# Rotativa gets 401.2 code status using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-401, rotativa

I have an MVC 5 project which uses Windows authentication.
In order of adding pdf export support, I try to set up Rotativa lib.
The first try was Controller method

```
public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("myAction");
}
```

which results as error 401.2 page in pdf file.
As i undestand (please let me know if there is another solution!!!), there is the only workaround:

```
public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
{
    return new ViewAsPdf("myView");
}
```

In this case, I get a pdf file, but it contents a web page withount javascript scripts completed!

So, the question: is any another solution instead of replace `ActionAsPdf` to `ViewAsPdf`? If no, is it a solution to make `ViewAsPdf` include javascript execution results?